# Как сделать запрос к БД цикличным?

Tags: php, wordpress, dle

Пишу я значит конвертер базы из `dle->wordpress`, простенький, ньюсонли.
Стоит вопрос - как этот кусок кода вставить в цикл, чтобы он вытаскивал не только первую запись в бд, а все? Do While(?);

```
// Коннект к базе DLE
    $db_dle = mysql_connect("localhost", "vf", "");
    mysql_select_db("vf", $db_dle);
    // Вытаскивание из БД DLE
    $result_dle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  dle_post", $db_dle);
    $array_dle = mysql_fetch_array($result_dle);
    // Коннект к базе WP
    $db_wp = mysql_connect("localhost", "social", "");
    mysql_select_db("social", $db_wp);
    // Ввод в БД WP
    $addpost = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_name, post_parent, menu_order, post_type) VALUES ('1', '$array_dle[date]', '$array_dle[date]', '$array_dle[short_story]', '$array_dle[title]', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '$array_dle[alt_name]', '0', '0', 'post')");

    echo $array_dle[title];
    echo " - Статья добавлена";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мда ... А может лучше не нужно ничего писать ?

```
// Коннект к базе DLE
$db_dle = mysql_connect("localhost", "vf", "");
mysql_select_db("vf", $db_dle);
// Коннект к базе WP
$db_wp = mysql_connect("localhost", "social", ""); 
mysql_select_db("social", $db_wp);

// Вытаскивание из БД DLE
$result_dle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  dle_post", $db_dle);
while($array_dle = mysql_fetch_array($result_dle)){
// Ввод в БД WP
$addpost = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_name, post_parent, menu_order, post_type) VALUES ('1', '$array_dle[date]', '$array_dle[date]', '$array_dle[short_story]', '$array_dle[title]', 'publish', 'open', 'open', '$array_dle[alt_name]', '0', '0', 'post')");

echo $array_dle[title];
echo " - Статья добавлена";
}
```

Comment: А подробнее? Что изменилось то? Оно как вытаскивало/добавляло 1ну первую запись также это и продолжает делает

Comment: да ладно, Вам же цикл нарисовали
>$result_dle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  dle_post", $db_dle);
while($array_dle = mysql_fetch_array($result_dle)){

вот это и будет выводить *все* записи из бд ДЛЕ и проганять их в цикле, пока они существуют, а
>$addpost = mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_posts 

будет вбивать в вп при каждом проходе цикла.
@shurik все верно написал.

Comment: Ой, извиняюсь, не заметил (: 
Сейчас проверю